# Sprite animation with size more than 3MB not showing on Firefox

Tags: html, css

Recently I am facing some problem with my code in sprite animation in firefox.

My sprite image file is containing high quality graphics so the size of the image is more than 3MB. The same image with same code is working fine in Chrome.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  body {

    background-color: grey
  }

  .myDiv {
    width: 650px;
    height: 650px;
    background: url(imagepath) top center;
    animation: animatename 4s steps(120) infinite;
  }

  @keyframes animatename {
    100% {
      background-position: 0px -78000px;
    }
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="myDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's with the random `<html>` tag after the `<div class='myDiv'></div>`?

Comment: I have misspelled it. Now i have edited the question. Please check